# Android Room Database Transaction with Active LiveData generate crash

Tags: android, transactions, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

For my database migration i am using `Transaction`. I am using below code

```
roomDb.beginTransaction();
try{
   roomDb.clearAllTables();
   // insert new data

   // if data generated successfully then set transaction successfull
   roomDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
}catch(Exception e){

}finally{
   roomDb.endTransaction();
}
```

Here if any `Exception` occur during data population then `roomBd.setTransactionSuccessful();` will not be called.

To test what happen when `roomBd.setTransactionSuccessful()` is not called i have commented that line. So i am not executing `roomBd.setTransactionSuccessful()` method.

Now i am facing  below crash.

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 5075

Scenario is i have active `LiveData` Observer for db `tables`. If i don't observe `LiveData` for my db tables then there is no crash for that transaction.

Why transaction without `setTransactionSuccessful()` being called generate a crash when there is active `LiveData` for tables.

The crash message seems like `memory` error.

How can i solve this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other stack trace. I can see only that message in Logcat

Comment: then share the functions clearALLTables(); and setTransactionSuccessfull();

Comment: Both methods are provided by by Room . Check here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html

Comment: why do you have 2 different instances roomDb and roomBd

Comment: the method setTransactionSuccessful is deprecated and runInTransaction(Runnable body) is the new method. check documentation  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html#runInTransaction(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: I think `runInTransaction` will behave same